Search fails because of type is illegal
When I try to run client.search() on my collection, I get the following error:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymilvus/client/check.py in _raise_param_error(param_name, param_value)
    220 def _raise_param_error(param_name: str, param_value: Any) -> None:
--> 221     raise ParamError(message=f"{param_name} value {param_value} is illegal")

Here's the description of my collection:
{'collection_name': 'TRIAL0_collection',
 'auto_id': False,
 'num_shards': 0,
 'description': 'RAG database collection',
 'fields': [{'field_id': 100,
   'name': 'id',
   'description': 'id',
   'type': <DataType.VARCHAR: 21>,
   'params': {'max_length': 50000},
   'is_primary': True},
  {'field_id': 101,
   'name': 'text',
   'description': 'chunk text',
   'type': <DataType.VARCHAR: 21>,
   'params': {'max_length': 50000}},
  {'field_id': 102,
   'name': 'vector',
   'description': 'embedding of the chunk',
   'type': <DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR: 101>,
   'params': {'dim': 768}},
  {'field_id': 103,
   'name': 'first_page',
   'description': 'first page the chunk appears in',
   'type': <DataType.VARCHAR: 21>,
   'params': {'max_length': 50000}},
  {'field_id': 104,
   'name': 'source',
   'description': 'file the chunk comes from',
   'type': <DataType.VARCHAR: 21>,
   'params': {'max_length': 50000}}],
 'aliases': [],
 'collection_id': 0,
 'consistency_level': 0,
 'properties': {},
 'num_partitions': 0,
 'enable_dynamic_field': True}

My data is simply the embedding of a query. It is done with the exact same model I embedded the chunks with. I checked the shape and size, and they are the same. My version of pymilvus is 2.4.4. I also checked this with a vector of just 0s and I get the same error.

Please include the full traceback error.
